# How to get value from multiple url localStorage

Tags: javascript

I want to get pointed url(row) localStorage value. Can I get this?

[image]

Comment: You mean like with `localStorage.get()`? Just pass in the URL as a string.

Comment: Also, unless you're really using *both* React and Angular and this question somehow relates to one or the other, those tags are not necessary.

Comment: @Pointy I want to get select https://branchbasics.referralcandy.com localStorage data but localStorage.get() not working and when i use localStorage.getItme(anykey) then it is searching in first index local storage row. but I want data from fifth one

Comment: @Pointy Okay, but if anybody knows ReactJs and Angular then he knows JavaScript also that's why I tagged that. anyway, thanks.

Comment: sorry I meant `.getItem()`. What doesn't work about it? The URL is just a string; how can it not work? What happens?

Comment: `let value = localStorage.getItem("https://branchbasics.referralcandy.com");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can access the local storage of `https://branchbasics.referralcandy.com` only if your JavaScript originates from that same server. This is a security measure of the browser implementation.

The browser stores are per origin, where "origin" is the same as for the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (a combination of schema [http vs. https, etc.], port, and host). From [web storage spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/):

> Each top-level browsing context has a unique set of session storage areas, one for each origin.

Thus, the storage for these examples are all different due to different origins:

- `http://example.com` and `http://foo.example.com` and  `http://bar.example.com`
- `http://example.com:80` and `http://example.com:8080` and `https://example.com`

There is no mechanism built into web storage that allows one origin to access the storage of another.

Pages within the same origin can access the same storage, such as `http://example.com/page1` and `http://example.com/page2` both have access to the storage for `http://example.com`.